# How to returns custom struct after sqlx query

Tags: sql, go

I'm a go beginner and I'm using Sqlx in my Rest API and I want to join 2 tables (the join isn't logic I'm just testing). Here is my model structs:

Ablum:

```
package album

import "github.com/.../api/v1/movie"

type Album struct {
    ID          string  `json:"id"`
    Title       string  `json:"title"`
    Artist      *string `json:"artist"`
    Price       float64 `json:"price"`
    MovieId     int     `json:"movie_id" db:"movie_id"`
    *movie.Movie `json:",omitempty" db:"movie"`
}
```

Movie:

```
package movie

type Movie struct {
    ID         string `json:"id"`
    Year       uint16 `json:"year"`
    RentNumber uint32 `json:"rent_number" db:"rent_number"`
    Title      string `json:"title"`
    Author     string `json:"author"`
    Editor     string `json:"editor"`
    Index      string `json:"index"`
    Bib        string `json:"bib"`
    Ref        string `json:"ref"`
    Cat1       string `json:"cat_1" db:"cat_1"`
    Cat2       string `json:"cat_2" db:"cat_2"`
}
```

So once I wrapped my Movie struct inside album I can do join query as well.
BUT I have a problem when I'm selecting certain columns:

```
func (r *Repository) FindAll() ([]Album, error) {
    var albums []Album

    err := r.db.Select(&albums, `SELECT album.title, movie.year "movie.year" FROM album inner join movie on (movie.id=album.movie_id)`)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Album.FindAll: %v", err)
    }

    return albums, nil
}
```

I selected just album.title and movie.year and the result of this is :

```
[
    {
        "id": "",
        "title": "Blue Train",
        "artist": null,
        "price": 0,
        "movie_id": 0,
        "year": 2017,
        "rent_number": 0,
        "author": "",
        "editor": "",
        "index": "",
        "bib": "",
        "ref": "",
        "cat_1": "",
        "cat_2": ""
    }
    ...
```

And what I want is just :

```
[
    {
        "title": "Blue Train",
        "year": 2017,
    }
    ...
```

I don't want use `omitempty` tag for this because sometimes if a field is null in my database I'd like to show it event it's null in my json. So what I want is to know what is the best way to handle this (to return my custom fields)

Should I create another struct with just 2 fields ? Or I can create another thing like `map[string]interface{}` (I'm not sure map is a good practice for this because we don't know the real type) ?

Maybe ORM can help ? But I'm not using ORM like GORM because everytime time I see the go community talking about it they say it's slow, not perf, it's not "go way" and personally I like to use pure SQL to query my database so I trust them

Comment: Note that a struct value in Go will *always* have *all* the fields with which its type was defined. It does not matter whether you've initialized the fields or not. Uninitialized fields are part of the struct value and they always will be part of the struct value. They are not magically removed from the value just because they are uninitialized. Sqlx or ORMs have absolutely nothing to do with your problem and they therefore will not be part of the solution. https://play.golang.org/p/ZWVHt4Pnuey

Answer (score -2):

I think a struct with these two field is a reasonable idea.